# React-Select, Async Option, no value displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
require("../node_modules/react-select/dist/react-select.css");   

const getOptions = (input) => {
      return fetch(`/games/uni/autocomplete/${input}`)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        }).then((json) => {

      console.log(json)
      return { options: json };
    });
}


var SearchBar = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
       return (

            <Select.Async
              name="form-field-name"
              loadOptions={getOptions} />   
    )
  }
});

export default SearchBar;
```

console.log(json) is like: `["EA SPORTS FIFA 16", "FIFA 16 Ultimate Team"]`

But the suggeestion values are empty

[image: empty select]

Here the state and props of the component Async

[image: props and state of component]

Here the official documentation with the example: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#async-options-with-promises

What im missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your console.log(json) you print out an array with strings in it, its not an array of objects.

Like the documentation says, you need to format your data like below. Before you are returning it.

**Example**

```
const json = [
 { value: 'EASPORTFIFA16', label: 'EA SPORTS FIFA 16' },
 { value: 'FIFA16UltimateTeam', label: 'FIFA 16 Ultimate Team' }
]
```

Comment: Same issue, I am returning an array of objects, and still getting an empty dropdown

Comment: @AvremelKaminetzky If your json response is not an array of objects with the properties "value" and "label," you can specify the value with the valueKey prop and the label with the labelKey prop...

Comment: You are right. But my issue was because i didn't explicitly return the fetch function.